# Sending mail via smtp in Django

Tags: python, django, shell, email, gmail

I'm trying to send a simple email using python/django shell and have been strugling with this problem for the last few hours:
in django shell i do the following:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('django mail', 'this was sent with django', 'myaddress@gmail.com',['myaddress@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

the returned result should be 1, meaning that the mail is sent successfully, but insead, i get this:

```
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu9\n5.7.14 0cv5jjPsAITCLvsSIKoDuJcz5I18H7PMX8Nsxz2ajtgAJfxls4wIKIVMUENCrFmoXNHdgM\n5.7.14 NpSKlFYuaGHtwqDodV09jIf_GaDklCUUzJLY7oSJITQqXADDWxYRU7LUbVRFPxwpd2cKzl\n5.7.14 g70grCboTaCtEofq3-5edwoRC0ukZT-z97AgOelTTvSteaEjuf5n7F417VvFFE1hXcBnyg\n5.7.14 n2NWXBFMlV_74532aXU0vguceCC84> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 2sm2181268wrn.24 - gsmtp')
```

I read the url suggested in the error, and also a few similar questions on the web, and there were no good it them for me.

also, in the `settings.py` file, the required code is included:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'  
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com'  
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'  
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

as i mentioned above, the other questions/problems on this site weren't the same. I've already enable the access for less secure apps on my gmail account, and also i have no two step verification.

Comment: Did you enable `less secure apps` in two places ?

Comment: what do you mean by "two places"?

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps bottom of the page and here is the another one https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: they are both in sync, when turn one off/on, the other one is updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC to send email using gmail SMTP from third-party apps (your own Django app), you need to enable what they call [Less Secure Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

You can read more here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255